# Report all ODBC DSN on workstations in the network

Tags: odbc, dsn

In preparation for retiring SQL Server A (2005) and deploying SQL Server B (2012), I've discovered numerous Microsoft Office assets (Excel, Access) that connect via ODBC DSNs.

Is there a method to scan all workstations on a network and return a report of DSN definitions?

PS: For the next step, I've read this:
[Managing mass SQL Server ODBC Changes when migrating to a new SQL Server](https://serverfault.com/questions/364300/managing-mass-sql-server-odbc-changes-when-migrating-to-a-new-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably just write a simple logon script to export the user's and machine's ODBC configuration from the registry and throw them into some . You're interested in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ODBC`. One challenge would be making sure that you get every user to logon and run the script.

DSN-less connections are going to be a problem for you, too. If you've got documents w/ embedded connection strings in them this isn't going to help you.